# Joomla 3: Permission to manage users and nothing else

Tags: joomla

I'm developing a Joomla 3 website, where registered users can belong to several groups of interests (music, theater, technology, and so on).

I would like to give permission to my client to edit users by placing them in groups he desired. For example: user 1 can be in music and theater group; user 2 just registered (no group) and user 3 in technology group. Unfortunately the only permission that Joomla 3 allows you to edit users is the Administrator, but if I give this permission to my client, he will be able to edit articles, themes and other features that I do not want it to edit.

How can I create an access level that can manage only users list?

Thank you and sorry about my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new group, assign that group only permission for managing users and whatever else you want and assign your users to that group but not admin.

Comment: Theres no option to allow permission only to managing users. If he is user-type, he can access the users, components, modules and plugins.

Comment: Of course there is, just go to the configuration for com_users and allow for that group. Or deny access to plugins and modules.

Comment: Where is the "configuration for com_users"?

Comment: Go to com_users, click on Options. Just like for every other component.

Comment: I got it! Thank you. I was confusing the com_users permissions with the permissions of the global configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As a short answer, if you don't want you client to be administrator, you can assign him to the manager user-group. 
Then go into the Users Manager Component and click the Options button to go into its configuration page. 
There you can override the Permissions Settings for the Users Manager component, so the Managers users will be allowed to Access Administration Interface of the component.

You will have the change the respective setting from inherit to allowed.

Of course if needed, you can create a complete custom ACL, with special usergroups for your users that will have certain accessibility and permissions.

But be careful, because ACL sometimes can be confusing and you might end up with a total mess.

Comment: Hello Frewin. If i change the Access Administration Interface permission to allowed, the manager can access all components and modules, which I don't want to. If I deny, he cannot see the user manager settings.

Comment: Why are you acting like you can't create a new group that is manager with the addition of access admin interface for com_users?

Comment: Like I said, I created a new group called "User manager", that is manager. But theres is no option to assign him to manage users without manage componentes, themes, modules and plugins.